# Как распознать улыбку на фото  ?

Tags: php

Как распознать улыбку на фото  ?

Comment: выбирайте задачи себе по силам

Comment: можно почти ничего не зная:
взять фотик с распознаванием улыбок, функцией записи этой информации в exif  и возможностью remote control с компа. Выводим картинку на монитор, фотаем монитор, читаем получившийся файл, наличие/координаты улыбки выбираем из EXIF.

Comment: На php нереализуймо.

Comment: @HappyCougar, прямо таки нереализуемо?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Самое близкое, что получилось найти - [PHP Face Detection](https://github.com/mauricesvay/php-facedetection) и [Face detection in images using PHP](http://www.codediesel.com/algorithms/face-detection-in-images-using-php/). Разберетесь с лицами - перейдете к улыбкам :)

Пример для ленивых с вырезанием лица:

```
include "FaceDetector.php";

$face_detect = new Face_Detector('detection.dat');
$face_detect->face_detect('файл-с-изображением');
$face_detect->cropFace();
```

Еще вариант: [OpenCV for PHP](https://github.com/mgdm/OpenCV-for-PHP).